# Is an expansion like this possible in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I want to do something similar to this:

```
apt install emacs-(ivy, emms, magit)
--->
apt install emacs-ivy emacs-emms emacs-magit
```

Is this possible to do with bash?

Comment: yes, `apt install emacs-{ivy,emms,magit}`

Comment: @mosvy Thanks a lot, I could not remember it nor find it!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is easily accomplished using a *brace expansion*:

```
apt install emacs-{ivy,emms,magit}
```

This would be expanded by the shell to

```
apt install emacs-ivy emacs-emms emacs-magit
```

before `apt` is called.

This type of brace expansion expands to each comma-separated word within `{...}`. If there is a prefix and/or suffix string attached to the curly braces (as there is in this example), this string would be duplicated for each word.

The other type of brace expansion is for ranges, as in `{0..10}` or `{k..z}`. This works in the analogous way, but with a range of either single alphabetical characters or numbers.

Brace expansions are fully documented in the `bash` manual (`man bash` at your terminal), in the section aptly named "Brace Expansion".

Brace expansions are supported by `bash` and by a few other common shells with varying expansion and formatting capabilities, but it's not a POSIX standard feature.